Good estimate for this the integral $\int_{\|x\|<R}e^{-\|x\|^2}dx_1\dots dx_m, x:=(x_1\dots x_m)$ in terms of $R,$ but possibly also $m?$
So I'm trying to come up with an accurate/tight estimate for
$$\int_{\|x\|<R}e^{-\|x\|^2}dx_1\dots dx_m, \quad x:=(x_1\dots x_m)$$
in terms of $R$ as $R\to \infty,$ or for large $R.$ Please note that by 'estimate', I'm looking for a function of $R,$ which is perhaps nicer.
But ideally an estimate/function in terms of both the radius $R$ and the dimension $m$ would be even better!
Thank you - reference appreciated!

You can simply compute it. Via polar coordinates \begin{align*}
I(R)=\int_{B_R}e^{-\vert x \vert^2} \, dx &= \int_0^R \int_{\partial B_\rho} e^{-\vert x \vert^2} \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x \, d\rho\\
&=n\omega_n\int_0^R \rho^{n-1}e^{-\rho^2} \, d \rho
\end{align*} where $\omega_n=\vert B_1\vert$ is the volume of the unit $n$-ball. Then the change of variables $\rho \to \rho^{1/2}$ gives \begin{align*}
I(R)&= \frac{n \omega_n}2\int_0^{R^2}\rho^{\frac n2-1}e^{-\rho} \, d \rho . \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*}Sending $R\to +\infty$, we obtain $$\lim_{R\to+\infty} I(R)=  \frac{n \omega_n}2\int_0^{+\infty}\rho^{\frac{n}2-1}e^{-\rho} \, d \rho=  \frac{n \omega_n}2\Gamma\bigg(\frac n 2 \bigg)  $$where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. Since $\omega_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma \big (\frac n 2 +1\big )}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{n\Gamma \big (\frac n 2\big )}$, we obtain $$\lim_{R\to+\infty} I(R)= \pi^{\frac n2}. $$

Higher order expansion:
From ($\ast$), it follows that \begin{align*}
I(R)-\pi^{\frac n2} &= \frac{n \omega_n}2\int_{R^2}^{+\infty}\rho^{\frac{n}2-1}e^{-\rho} \, d \rho \\
&=\frac{n \omega_n}2\Gamma \bigg ( \frac n2 , R^2\bigg)
\end{align*} where $\Gamma(a,z)$ is (upper) incomplete Gamma function. Then Eqn 8.11.2 on the database of mathematical function gives $$\Gamma (a,z) =z^{a-1}e^{-z} \bigg ( \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^k(1-a)_k}{z^k} +O(z^{-N}) \bigg )  $$ for fixed $a$ and $z\to+\infty$ where $(\cdot)_k$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol. Hence, \begin{align*}
I(R)&=\pi^{n/2}+\frac{n \omega_n}2R^{n-2}e^{-R^2} \bigg ( \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^k(1-n/2)_k}{R^{2k}} +O(R^{-2N}) \bigg ) \\
&= \pi^{n/2}+\frac{n \omega_n}2R^{n-2}e^{-R^2} \big (1+\frac{(n-2)}{2R^{2}}+ \dots \big )  
\end{align*}
Please double-check the exact numbers. There could easily be a typo :)

Thank you, but I guess I'm interested in the estimate for $I(R)$ in terms of $R,$ especially for large $R.$ It's clear to me that it must be related to the Gamma function in some way, but some nice growth formula in terms of $R$ is what I'm after. Thanks and upvoted in any case.
Also is $\omega_n$ the area/volume of the unit $n$ sphere, if I'm not mistaken?

It's probably worth noting that this simplifies to $\pi^{n/2}$.

This correctly computes the integral over $\mathbb{R}^m$, but the question is about the rate of convergence of the integral in terms of $R$ and $m$. With the language of my answer, this computes the zeroth-order Taylor expansion, but we might want to compute higher orders as well.

@LearningMath  I've updated my answer to use higher-order expansion. I realised that I wrote $n$ instead of $m$ - sorry force of habit. Also, $\omega_n$ is the volume of the $n$-ball. With this notation, the area/volume of the $(n-1)$-sphere is $n\omega_n$

@ChristianE.Ramirez Thank you for the comment - I updated the answer

@GiuseppeNegro See the updated answer :)

Great, we find the same exponential decay of $e^{-R^2}$, and also the same constant in front, but we do not agree on the exponent of $R$ (I found $R^n$). Anyway, that might not be a contradiction since my estimate is not a Taylor expansion.

Good edit, but you do have it a bit wrong. It should be $\pi^{n/2}$ rather than $\pi^{1/2}$. See here.

@ChristianE.Ramirez Ah yes, thanks

We know that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-\lvert x \rvert^2}\, dx=\pi^\frac{d}{2}.$$
So the integral we want to estimate reads
$$
I_R=\pi^\frac{d}{2} - \int_{\lvert x\rvert> R} e^{-\lvert x \rvert^2}\, dx.$$
Letting $r=\lvert x \rvert$ and $\rho=1/r$, we get
$$\tag{*}\int_{\lvert x\rvert> R} e^{-\lvert x \rvert^2}\, dx= \lvert \mathbb S^{d-1}\rvert \int_0^{1/R} e^{-\rho^{-2}}\rho^{-(d+1)}\, d\rho,$$
where $\lvert \mathbb S^{d-1}\rvert= \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$. We can bound this integral as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^{1/R} e^{-\rho^{-2}}\rho^{-(d+1)}\, d\rho &\le\frac{1}{R}\sup_{\rho\in (0,1/R)} e^{-\rho^{-2}}\rho^{-(d+1)}
\\&\le \frac{1}{R}\sup_{t\in (R, \infty)} e^{-t^2}t^{d+1}=R^d e^{-R^2}, \\
\end{split}
$$
provided $R$ is bigger than $\sqrt{(d+1)/2}$, which is where the derivative of $e^{-t^2}t^{d+1}$ becomes negative. The conclusion is the estimate, for $R\ge \sqrt{(d+1)/2}, $
$$
\pi^\frac{d}{2}\ge I_R\ge \pi^\frac{d}{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{\Gamma(d/2)}e^{-R^2}R^d\right).$$
